# My footer keeps overlapping

Tags: html, css

I've searching over the internet and I've added that was recommenced but it seems like the footer is still over lapping my page. Would anyone know why?

```css
footer {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .93);
```

So, on the forums I went on they said to set the min hight to 100%

```css
    min-height: 100%;
```

Set the position but the same result is coming up.

```css
    position: relative;
}
h4 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'open_sansbold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 13em;
}
footer p {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'open_sansbold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: WOW you sure like whitespace, don't you?

Comment: Quite new to this. How to i make it more simple?

Comment: If you could link the page or make a demonstration in the Snippet Editor or at least jsfiddle, it'd really help

Comment: do you have the css for what its overlapping into?

Comment: Yes, i do. I'm not sure how i add my code inside. I just started using this yesterday. Would know i can send you what i've done?

Comment: you can hop on here,http://jsfiddle.net/,  add your code and share the link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bejwrces/

Comment: seems to be working just fine with me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: ps your closing tag is broken on your <h4>VISIT ME:</h5>

Comment: that fiddle seems fine regards the footer. what is overlapping and what is it overlapping into?

Comment: i'm using chrome and thanks. The only problem now is the footer is now massive. @Craicerjack no i haven't, am i aloud to do that?

Comment: The footer is probably massive because youve set the min-height to 100% - remove the min-height and see how it is

Comment: if you right-click on an item in chrome and select inspect element you can check out the css and edit it live on the page to see how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of making sure is to add an empty div above it about the same size as the footer.  this will push the footer down and remove the overlay.

```
<body>
    <div style="height:400px;"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact desired outcome, and I didn't see overlapping (after fixing the h4 tag... but changing your height and padding-bottom (if desired) fixes the size.  http://jsfiddle.net/dsbf72tp/

```
footer {

    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .93);
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    }
```